# SQL SP: Dynamic Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying get a `col` and `value` as a function parameter and planning to use them in a query.

Unfortunately, my value for `@Col` is being treated like a `string` and not a column identifier.

ie, if I specify `name` as a value for the `@Col` parameter, it will be treated like `'name'` instead of `name` and hence, the call to the function always returns `NULL` as a result

Have you came across similar situations? Could you please recommand me a better way to deal with this situation?

Here is my Function for your reference:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_FindIdBy] 
(
    @Col NVARCHAR(255),
    @Value NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id INT = NULL

    SET @Id = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.MYWORK WHERE (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), @Col) = @Value))
    IF @Id IS NOT NULL RETURN @Id

    RETURN NULL
END
```

Thanks a lot for looking into this.

Comment: You won't be able to do this dynamically in a function, because you can't perform dynamic SQL in a function.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: What would you recommend instead?

Comment: @Moon You could consider using a Stored Procedure instead

Comment: I'm not sure, I am having a hard time understanding the ultimate goal (which is not to have dynamic SQL in a function or have a function dynamically pick the ID). For better clues please post table structure and explain why you don't know the column name until runtime.

Comment: @Moon Could you please provide a couple example columns?  Also, how many columns are in this table, and what possible types could you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works, but you have to use it as a procedure and create dynamic sql.

```
create table MYWORK (ID int identity, Name nvarchar(255))

insert into MYWORK(Name)
select 'a'
union select 'b'
union select 'c'
union select 'd'
union select 'e'
union select 'f'


CREATE procedure [dbo].[EPG_FN_FindIdBy] 
@Col NVARCHAR(255),
@Value NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id nvarchar(255)
    , @ParmDefinition nvarchar(255)
    , @sql nvarchar(max)

    set @sql = N'SELECT @IdOUT = ID FROM dbo.MYWORK WHERE '+ @Col +' = ''' + @Value + ''''
    set @ParmDefinition = N'@IdOUT nvarchar(255) OUTPUT'

    PRINT @sql

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,@ParmDefinition, @IdOUT = @Id OUTPUT
    SELECT @Id as ID

END
```

Run this and it'll return the matching row

```
Exec dbo.EPG_FN_FindIdBy @Col = 'Name', @Value = 'a'
```

And for a NULL

```
Exec dbo.EPG_FN_FindIdBy @Col = 'Name', @Value = 'g'
```

Comment: +1 - you were a bit faster than me :) Two problems with this though: 1) you left out the 'convert(nvarchar,...)' thing; 2) when not found, it's supposed no return a NULL value, not an empty result set

Comment: One more thing - the dynamic SQL approach could be vulnerable to SQL injection - so, @Moon, you have to make sure you control the values passed to the procedure

Comment: Thanks!  I don't believe the convert is necessary since it was being done on the column name, but I'll edit the code for returning a NULL

Comment: it is necessary if, for example, the column is of type `int`. So, provided that we don't know much about the table structure, you might include it for safety.

Comment: No, I believe it was attempted on the OUTPUT of the column name, not the name itself (the name itself was already an nvarchar(255), why would it need to be converted?).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Exactly, on the OUTPUT of the column, not the name. If the filtered column was of type `int`, the above script would be comparing `1` with `'1'`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there's almost always a better way to query than using dynamic SQL.

Check out this usage of the CASE operator.

```
SELECT id
FROM dbo.MYWORK
WHERE CASE @Col
    WHEN 'a' THEN [a]
    WHEN 'b' THEN [b]
    WHEN 'c' THEN [c]
    END = @Value
```

Where the table has columns [a], [b] and [c].

Comment: There are two problems with this: (1) you have to type out all of the columns and (2) you need a separate case structure for each set of compatible data types.

Comment: The first point you made is _not_ an actual problem, it's just lazy programming.  How many columns can you really have.  And, yes, you can add a CASE...CAST to the second part, _if_ (big if) the columns hold different value types.

Comment: I've seen 200+ columns, especially in EAV, which this seems to be. So it's not impossible to do, but it's quite tedious and brittle if there are changes to the underlying schema. Also why do you think it's a big if that not all of the columns are `NVARCHAR(255)`? The `CONVERT` is a big hint to me that the data types can differ.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Well, now I'm confused.  Just looked up EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value, correct?) on Wikipedia, and it looks like that table structure has very _few_ columns.  By columns, do you mean entries, or logical rows?  I think what's throwing me off here is the irregular usage of those table (EAV) types.

Comment: Sorry, looking back what I said was slightly confusing. I meant a normalized version of EAV, where you have a column for each possible value (columns = hair color, eye color, weight, height, shoe size, waist size, etc). You're right, true EAV would be the opposite, columns = attribute and value. Anyway, it's the former I'm suspecting is at play here.

Comment: A thought: looking at the CONVERT statement, only the column name is converted as well, not the value portion.  This leads me to believe that either (1) all values are VARCHAR types or (2) the query in the question was written incorrectly.

Comment: This is getting tedious, but I don't think you're right. Replace `@col` with the actual column name that was passed in (let's say `@col = N'foo'`). The *intended* query then becomes `WHERE (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), foo) = @Value))` ... right? We're still not converting the value itself directly (as that is already `NVARCHAR(255)`).